# Can I use mixed units with 'path' element?

Tags: html, svg

SVG has a rectangle element which dimensions could be specified in percent of dimensions of its owner and radius in pixels. So by doing the following

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<object class="AIRound" type="image/svg+xml"
data="data:image/svg+xml,<svg
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><rect x='0' y='0' width='100%'
height='100%' rx='10px' ry='10px' fill='#99ff99'
opacity='0.9'/></svg>" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;
width:100%; height:100%; z-index:-100;"></object>
Sample text<br>Sample text
Sample text<br>Sample text
</div>
```

I can get a  with rounded corners with the constant radius which doesn't depends on the block size. But a simple rectangle with rounded corners it's boring and sometimes you want something fancy (e. g. http://my.opera.com/). I've tried to use 'path' element but it seems to me we can't use mixed units with 'path' (pixels & percents). I can't use a combination of shapes either because it won't work semitransparents and gradient fill.

So my qeustion is can I use 'path' element with mixed units? Maybe there's another work around which I overlooked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paths and point-lists can only be specified in user units. By having a container (e.g an svg or symbol element) that specifies a new coordinate system with 'viewBox' it's possible to affect what the user units resolve to. That still doesn't solve all cases.

To fix a few more cases you can build the image using multiple shapes each with a different clip-path to clip away the parts that are undesirable. You can have a look at the [Rounded Corner Generator](http://a.deveria.com/roundgen/) SVG output for an example of that approach.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, path coordinates can only be expressed with a single unit, Viewport Coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

```
<svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
<!-- Now in here, a coordinate (25,50) corresponds to
     (25%,50%) of the outer viewport. -->
<path d="M36,96 C 54,100 94,73 97,61 ..."/>
</svg>
```

Ref: 
http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/Specyfing-paths-with-percentages-unit-td247474.html