# SVG and DPI, absolute units and user units: Inkscape vs. Firefox vs. ImageMagick

Tags: svg

I try to auto-generate an SVG file intended to be printed on a certain size (A4). I wish to use a path in it, which only allows 'user units', not 'absolute units'.

It seems to me that it is impossible to 'publish' an SVG file that has absolute units (e.g. document size) and a path *anywhere*, because I cannot get it to work properly across viewers.

Is there a way to get some consistency in rendering, like specifying a 'default DPI'?

Or put differently: Can I get my example below to render the same in all viewers without abandoning absolute units at all?

Related: Is there a way to force any of the applications below to render the image in the same way as one of the others? (E.g. I tried the `-density` option of 'convert', but I couldn't get the output to match Inkscape's or Firefox' output.)

---

Example:

I've created one SVG file, with three black squares (rect) with a red diagonal (path):

- Left: square and diagonal in user units
- Middle: square and diagonal in inch (seemed to me the most logical choice, but is not allowed)
- Right: square in mm, diagonal in user units

Which renders differently in different viewers:

- Inkscape: 90 DPI, all squares same size, red diagonal matches
- Firefox: 96 DPI?, latter squares to large (or diagonal to short)
- Convert: 72 DPI, latter squares to small (or diagonal to long)

[Code](http://www.astro.rug.nl/~buddel/files/svgtestunits/testunits2.svg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="200mm"
   height="100mm"
   >
  <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <rect
       width="100."
       height="100."
       x="10"
       y="10" />
    <path style="stroke: #ff0000" d="M 10 10 L 110 110" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(200,50)">
    <rect
       width="1.111in"
       height="1.111in"
       x="0.1111in"
       y="0.1111in" />
    <path style="stroke: #ff0000" d="M 0.1111in 0.1111in L 1.111in 1.111in" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(350,50)">
    <rect
       width="1.111in"
       height="1.111in"
       x="0.1111in"
       y="0.1111in" />
    <path style="stroke: #ff0000" d="M 10 10 L 110 110" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Inkscape (my default 'viewer'):

[image]

Firefox (note that the red line does not reach the lower right corner. I made a screenshot and cropped sort of arbitrarily):

[image: Firefox]

ImageMagick (convert, no options besides filenames given):

[image]

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132269/can-i-use-mixed-units-with-path-element useful to explain the problem.

Comment: Inkscape [0.92](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.92#Important_changes): The default resolution was changed from 90dpi to 96dpi, to match the CSS standard.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

All dimensions in a ***path*** tag are in user units.

You cannot specify absolute units within a ***path*** tag, which is why the path in the middle square does not render.

The simplest way I have found is to set the units using ***viewbox***:

- Set the width & height in inches.
- Then set the viewbox to be the same.
- This sets the user unit to be one inch.
- All sizes are then specified in inches (note: I used lower case l in path tag to specify a relative move)

This displays correctly in Inkscape and Firefox.

```
<svg
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    width="8in"
    height="4in"
    viewBox="0 0 8 4">

    <g transform="translate(4,0.5)">
        <rect
            width="1.111"
            height="1.111"
            x="0.1111"
            y="0.1111" />
        <path d="M 0.1111,0.1111 l 1.111 1.111" style="stroke: #ff0000;stroke-width:0.01"  />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This indeed seems to work as expected! The images produced by inkscape, ff and convert all look the same but have a different size that corresponds to the 96:90:72 ratios in the default dpi. At least in inkscape this is easy to change, anyone an idea how to get convert to produce the same?. Both inkscape and convert can create pdf's that print a box with line that is 1.1111 inch in size.

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand the -density option from convert. This works: to change the default dpi from 72 to FFs 96 you have to specify sqrt(96*72)=83.1 as density (for the input file). So 'convert -density 83.1 inputfile.svg outputfile.png' gives the same image as firefox does.

Comment: @BlackShift ImageMagick's `convert` command takes a `-density XX` argument (before you specify the input file) to set the resolution.

Comment: @Caleb yeah, what I don't understand is why I should specify sqrt(96*72)=83.1 as input density to let convert produce the same png image as a Firefox screenshot (a box of 108 pixels, including 1 px boundary). At least for FF 45.0.2 and ImageMagick 6.7.2-7, perhaps it is different in newer versions.

Comment: I think I understand why this works, but if I set the viewBox to match the width and height, and *then* use absolute units, why doesn't it match the user units (in Inkscape and Firefox)? Is there still some opaque default-DPI conversion going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4):

I have had a similar issue using [Apache Batik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batik_(software)) to embed an SVG file in a PDF file using [iText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IText). iText uses 72 DPI, the standard for PDF, while Batik uses 96.

To get the image to appear correctly, that is, to scale, in the PDF file, you need to divide the width=x cm height=y cm in the SVG header by 1.33 (96/72).